# Simple lightweight high power amplifier circuit

Tags: power, transistors, amplifier

I'm looking for a way to amplify a 12V sinusoidal signal to drive a set of transducers at ~120V with an overall power of 100W.

The quality of the output signal does not have to be good, simplicity and low weight are more important. In fact I would be happy for the signal just to go rail to rail, but obviously then the transistors would have to be able to handle a 240V swing.
I have studied basic BJT amplifier circuits and I have been playing around with basic circuit simulation software but I haven't been able find anything that would do this

Comment: Why not use a transformer?

Comment: What frequency?

Comment: The frequency is around 2.5MHz, and I don't want to use a transformer as the signal will be coming from a small digital signal generator then converted to analogue and it wouldn't be able to handle the current required for 100W

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Power BJT's. These BJT's are capable to handle lot more power than the simple BJT's.There are more number of Power BJT's available in market.

  They can surely handle 240V and even higher amount of voltages.

  Just google out for the transistor which can handle the power and voltage you expect.That's it

  If you don't need good amplification,then you can use class A type of amplifier circuit.They are less efficient.

  Make sure to use a heat sink,because they'll generate lot of heat during operation.